# keep html, css, javascript or anything <between-these-brackets> unchanged and rest to be converted in ASCII Characters

Tags: java, html, string

I want to keep HTML, CSS, JS or whatever inside  as it is and
to convert the text resides outside these brackets into ASCII Characters.

For example looking for: `<b>Hello World</b>` 
Required output is: `<b>  &#72;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111; &#87;&#111;&#114;&#108;&#100;  </b>`

What I experimented so far is:
I applied ASCII Characters with java code e.g.: `str.replace("H", "&#72;")` but certainly it's changing both inside and outside tags as:

```
&#60;&#98;&#62;     &#72;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111; &#87;&#111;&#114;&#108;&#100; &#60;/&#98;&#62;
```

It prints only `<b>Hello World</b>` rather then applying as html code.

I am looking for the solution to keep html, css, javascript or anything  unchanged and rest to be converted in ASCII Characters

**Please NOTE:** Hello World is dynamic value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/wT9R07/1), `(?<=>)([^<]*)(?=<)` to find the text between HTML tags. After extracting the text, you can split it on each character and then cast each character into `int` in order to get its ASCII value.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "<b>Hello World</b>";
        System.out.println(convert(str));
    }

    static String convert(String str) {
        String regex = "(?<=>)([^<]*)(?=<)";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String match = matcher.group();
            if (!match.isBlank()) {
                return str.replaceAll(regex,
                        " " + Arrays.stream(match.split(""))
                                .map(s -> !" ".equals(s) ? ("&#" + (int) Character.valueOf(s.charAt(0)) + ";") : " ")
                                .collect(Collectors.joining()) + " ");
            }
        }

        return str;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<b> &#72;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111; &#87;&#111;&#114;&#108;&#100; </b>
```

---

Explanation of the regex by regex101.com:

[image]

Comment: Upvote++ for your great answer but when I use in servlet and calling method its throwing this error: `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
 at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:712)`

Comment: I am using apache-tomcat-9.0.43

Comment: Your code only converts html. I found when <script> or <style> is coming then its not working. Can there be any solution for that?

Comment: @User169 It has nothing to do with the servlet container. The above code can fail when input `String` is empty `<b></b>`, add a check for it. Also, your post looks like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve? Does this have an actual use-case? If you are only trying to render an HTML Document then this seems to be a network-intensive job for large inputs. You can save some processing power and network by encoding it on the client-side.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Yes this is actual use-case and task is to skip html tags, js and css code but to convert text into ASCII characters.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who is helping me in this project but with due respect please pay attention to the detail as I am not only looking for HTML but JS and CSS is also the intentions to fix in the code

Comment: @AniketSahrawat - You are right that the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` was because of not checking empty tags. I've updated the answer to deal with this case.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks for adding `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` block but now its not converting at all because if tag is null then exiting block and not converting

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash is that possible if tag is empty then skip and run the rest of the code because isblank() check is skipping whole block and doing nothing. So running this code become useless

Answer (score 0):

`JSoup` does the job nicely and efficiently, with the least amount of code needed:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Parser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<b>Hello World!</b>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements elements = doc.select("*:not(html):not(head):not(body)");
        for(Element e : elements) {
            String tagName = e.tagName();
            if(!tagName.equals("#root")) {
                System.out.println("<"+tagName+">"+convertToAscii(e.html())+"</"+tagName+">");
            }
        }
    }
    public static String convertToAscii(String text) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        int len = text.length();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            str.append("&#"+(int)text.charAt(i)+";");
        }
        return str.toString();
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
<b>&#72;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111;&#32;&#87;&#111;&#114;&#108;&#100;&#33;</b>
```

Import JSoup in `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```